# How Can I Handle a Parent's RoutedEvent?

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabcontrol, routed-events

I want to handle the TabControl's SelectionChanged event in one of its child TabItems only. How can I do this?

I've tried

```
<TabControl Name="tbcTab">
    <TabItem Selector.SelectionChanged="tbcTab_SelectionChanged"/>
    ....
```

and it doesn't work. TabItem doesn't seem to have any other way of knowing when it's become the selected one.

Comment: Can I ask you why do you need it?

Comment: I need it because the TabItem contains a TextBox to which I am setting the focus when the tab gets selected.

Answer (score 0):

Gotcha - just do it the other way around - listen to the event at your `TabControl` level then check

`System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs.AddedItems[0]` - if it's what you expect  -act.

Comment: That's the way I'm doing it, I just wondered if I could handle it in the TabItem directly to avoid the if logic.